# How should I add alphabets in Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net

i wanted to do something like

```
ab_1
ab_2
ab_3
```

but don't know how to add the `ab` inside this coding.

i just want simple one as i am new to coding

```
 aUTO id

        myconnection.Open()

        Dim str As String

        str = "Select MAX([EmployeeID]) from HR_Employee_Details"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
        Dim rd As OleDbDataReader

        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        If rd.HasRows Then

            rd.Read()

            str = Convert.ToInt32(rd(0))

            str = str + 1

            txtHREmployeeInfoEmployeeID.Text = str

        Else

            txtHREmployeeInfoEmployeeID.Text = "1"

        End If

        myconnection.Close()


    End Sub
```

as long i can add the `ab` should be okay

Comment: Why are you incrementing EmployeeID in code? The database can do that work for you with an auto-number field  ( also called auto-increment or identity field) This is a common set up for a Primary Key. If there is ever more than a single user of your app, you may get duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

your question as well as code is very unclear. 
but try using simple string concatenation if you want to just add "ab_" in front of all employee ID's you are pulling out from database.
`txtHREmployeeInfoEmployeeID.Text = "ab_"+str`

Comment: hai,
Ohw really? once i did this, -->> "str = Convert.ToInt32(rd(0))" its showing this as error.

Comment: (Conversion from string "ab_4" to type 'Double' is not valid.) this is what its showing once i change the ToInt32 to toString .  THIS ERROR

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a numeric value to a string variable in the first place?